Cannot send email with `symfony/mailer`, but native function `mail` works
I have a server configured with DKIM and the native mail function seems to respect that and sends out emails without a problem.
However, I need to use symfony/mailer (wrapped by yiisoft/yii2-symfonymailer) and I cannot get it to work. If I use the default SmtpTransport, I get the following error:
550-Verification failed for <XXXX>
550-Unrouteable address
550 Sender verify failed

If I use the built-in transport native://default it fails silently (as expected).
Any idea what I can do here? I'm about to write my own Transport class which simply uses mail, but that's obviously kind of ridiculous...

Have you tried sendmail://default? mail() uses the sendmail binary (unless you are on Windows).

@yivi I did, same result, I ended up writing a stupid TransportInterface implementation that just uses the native mail function, and it works...

You need to show some code, ie. how did you configure SMTP options? Can you show deep debug log? Did you check SMTP settings with your hosting service documentation?
